# Javascript RegEx Find Variable String Without Substring?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring

```
var str = "Visit tEsT!"; 
var ara = "test";
let n = str.search(/\b + ara + \b/i); // Sadly code doesn't run
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
```

I want find `ara` variable in `str` variable with regex `search()`.

Comment: Pleas explain clearly what is the result you want..

Comment: İ want find "ara" variable in "str" variable with regex search().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a new regex from a string in order to use variables.You can do this with `new RegExp()`. You will also need the [`i`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) option for case insensitive mode.

```
var str = "Visit tEsT!"; 
var ara = "test";
var regex = new RegExp(`\\b${ara}\\b`, 'i'); // Evaluates to "/\btest\b/i"
let n = str.search(regex);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
```

Comment: Thank you for fastly help :)

Comment: ara.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '') @FZs

Answer (score 2):

You have to put variables like this in Regex:

```js
var str = "Visit tEsT!"; 
var ara = "test";
let n = str.search(new RegExp(`\\b${ara}`,"i")); 
console.log(n);
```

More secure way is to remove special chars:

```
str.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s\n]/g,"")
```

```js
var str = "Visit tEsT!"; 
var searchstr = "test &#";
let n = str.search(new RegExp(`\\b${searchstr.replace(/[^A-Za-z\\s\\n]/g,"")}`,"i")); 
console.log(n);
```

Comment: Thank you for fastly help :)

Answer (score 1):

In your regular expression, you cannot use the `+` operator as a string concatenator. Instead, you could use for example [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and create the regular expression with `new RegExp`:

```
var str = "Visit tEsT!"; 
var ara = "test";
var regex = new RegExp(`\\b${ara}\\b`, 'gi');  // use 'gi' flags to search globally and ignore case
let n = str.search(regex);
console.log(n);
```

Comment: You can use `+` for concatenation. You also need to escape `\b`

Comment: Thank you for fastly help :)

Comment: @ButchMonkey Thanks for your advice. I thought I had to double escape but the PlayCode.io syntax highlighting confused me...

Comment: NP. I should clarify that you can use `+` for concatenation in `new RegExp` as it creates a regex from string. But you are correct that you cannot use `+` in `/.*/g` syntax as it will be evaluated

Answer (score 1):

If you want the matched string, use match() instead. The return value n will be an array and its first value (n[0]) will be the matched string.

```
var str = "Visit tEsT!"; 
var ara = "test";
var regexp = new RegExp("\\b"+ara+"\\b", 'gi')
n = str.match(regexp);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help too i maked search engine for my blog but if i use indexOf() visitor search value "a" then it show all articles ... İ just want to filter with regex to make results better...

Comment: Why do you want to show the index of the matched expression? That's what String.prototype.search() does.

Comment: `let str = 'B ad ga';
let result  = str.search('a');
document.write(result);`  but when i run this code, answer is: "2" so search() like indexOf()

Comment: Yes. It's exactly like indexOf except it expects a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Using `search` and `match` multiple ways.

```js
var str = "Visit tEsT!"; 
var ara = "test";
let n = str.search(new RegExp('\\b' + ara + '\\b', 'i'))

let n2 = str.match(new RegExp('\\b' + ara + '\\b', 'i')).index;

//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;

console.log(n, n2)
```